# get info from wikipedia

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Is there anithing for getting the main description of a wikipedia's page?

Like in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiohead

I want obtaing:

Radiohead are an English alternative rock band from Abingdon, Oxfordshire, formed in 1985. The band consists of Thom Yorke (lead vocals, rhythm guitar, piano, beats), Jonny Greenwood (lead guitar, keyboard, other instruments), Ed O'Brien (guitar, backing vocals), Colin Greenwood (bass guitar, synthesizers) and Phil Selway (drums, percussion).
...
Radiohead's work has appeared in a large number of listener polls and critics' lists.[2][3]  For example, in 2005 Radiohead were ranked number 73 in Rolling Stone's list of "the greatest artists of all time".[4]  While the band's earlier albums were particularly influential on British rock and pop music,[5]  their later albums brought them a wide audience.[6]  Their work has influenced other musicians in genres ranging from jazz and classical music to hip hop and R&B.[7][8][9][10]

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Ruby on Rails specific solution. Use the [wikipedia-client](http://code.google.com/p/wikipedia-client/) plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia based on MediaWiki engine. You can use a [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API).

Answer (score 0):

I know there's a Wikipedia API from Wikipedia Labs that's available. It's still in Beta phase. It uses Web Services, so I don't know how to do Web Services in RoR.

Source: http://wikipedia-lab.org/en/index.php/Wikipedia_API.

**EDIT**: If you are keen to read the **actual** Wikipedia API, visit site [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php). It's a RESTful API, with methods to call and how to retrieve information from Wikipedia. It's based from the WikiMedia Wiki API engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download dumps of Wikipedia (in many languages) and other projects, both in XML and in HTML. [Wikipedia:Database download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download) gives you the low-down.